# Speeding up appending text in C#

Tags: c#, performance, strings, speed

I'm trying to append text to a large amount of strings (in the thousands), and also do some other string manipulations.

However, I have about 60 lines of if/else and string appending and it takes several minutes to go through so many lines of text.

It does several checks, but the main part of it uses:

```
newstring += appendText.Text + ' ' + inputTextBox.Lines[i];
```

Is there a better way to do this that makes it faster?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking correctly, appending text using plus operator is not optimal. Use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, especially if conditionals are used:

(code from link above)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      
sb.Append("This is a sentence.");
      
for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 10; ctr++) {
    sb.Append("This is an additional sentence.");             
}
```

Than call `sb.ToString();` to show full string.

Note: There are at least 6 ways to concatenate a string in c# (all examples produce "a b"):

- '+' operator: use for constant strings, when it makes visual sense in code
- [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (.net 4.6 and newer): `var b = "b"; $"a {b}"`
- [string.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx): `string.Concat("a", " b")`
- [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx): `string.Format("{0} b", "a")`
- [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

  string[] arr = { "a", "b" };
  string.Join(" ", arr);
- [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usually, if you use .net 4.6 you will want to use string interpolation for shorter ones, and `StringBuilder` for longer. Prior to .net 4.6 insted of interpolation, use `string.Format()`.